# PhpStorm Not Displaying PHPDoc Class Properties Less Than 5 Characters

Tags: php, properties, annotations, phpstorm, phpdoc

I have come across a unique issue! Would appreciate any help anyone can provide!

I have created a class and defined read only properties using PHPDoc.

Within PhpStorm I am only able to see `Group`, `Message` and `MessageDetail` as accessible / pre-defined properties from the class "IntelliSense" popup.

When I add a 5th character, the property becomes visible. This makes me feel like it is probably a PhpStorm setting somewhere.

But I would be incredibly frustrated if this was a PhpStorm setting and that its default would automatically ignore manually defined properties less than 5 characters.

Any insights appreciated!

Cheers!

```
<?php

/**
 * @property-read   mixed                                       $ID
 * @property-read   array                                       $Group
 * @property-read   \Helpers\System\Chronology\DateTime         $Date
 * @property-read   \Enum\Language\Construct\Results\ResultType $Type
 * @property-read   string                                      $Message
 * @property-read   string                                      $MessageDetail
 * @property-read   mixed                                       $Data
 */
class Custom {
```

Comment: [That shouldn't be happening.](https://imgur.com/BLUpQLb) Which version of PhpStorm? Did you try with a new dummy class to make sure it wasn't some sort of cache/indexing issue?

Comment: Works just fine here: https://postimg.cc/crrm3S0N . Try your code sample in a brand new empty project to start with. `File | Invalidate Caches` and restart may also help.